# Files (Nautilus) appearing twice in GNOME dash (Ubuntu Dock)

Tags: 18.04, usb, nautilus, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Ever since installing Ubuntu 18.04, I've been having the following intermittent fault in my GNOME dash. For no discernible reason, I will have an extra shortcut to Files (i.e. Nautilus) appear on my GNOME dash in addition to the one that I already have as a favorite and this will not go away until reboot.

- Closing all occurrences of Files will not have any effect, nor will
  removing the old Files from my favorites (aside from removing the
  original occurrence of Files).
- The new Files shortcut can be added to favorites (and then removed),
  but this will also do nothing if Files is already favorited. If Files
  is not favorited, it will favourite a new instance of Files that
  works just like the oldest one.
- If clicked, the new shortcut does not open Files under its own icon. Instead, if will either use the old shortcut as the
  location of the application (i.e. Files is managed as if it was
  opened by the old shortcut), or if Files is not a favorite,
  it will make a new icon for Files that works as any other
  non-favorite application should.

This tends to happen infrequently, but I suspect that sleep mode may have some part in the blame.

Update: After a series of misclicks I've just seen this issue occur. I don't know if these misclicks have caused the issue, but I've just seen it triggered by opening Files via the 'Places status indicator' GNOME extension whilst in the 'Show Applications' menu of Ubuntu. I'm fairly confident that I was having this issue prior to having said extension installed, but it's a start.

Update 2: Uninstall the Places status indicator' GNOME extension fixed the issue for a while, but I've just trigger it again by putting a USB drive in and copying a few files to it before (safely) removing said drive.

Update 3: 'Open with Files' seems to be the culprit.

Update 4: This even appears to be replicable via 'Open with Files' after a download.

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried removing Nautilus from the dock ('remove from favourites') and re-adding?

Comment: @pomsky I'm sure that I have. From memory, the extra icon persists and the original one if, of course, removed and re-added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04 and found that there is an additional `.desktop` entry for nautilus under the `/usr/share/applications` directory (`nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`).
This happened after I opened an archive and extracted it with the '*open with other application*' -> '*Files*' option.

Just remove the extra `nautilus-folder-handler.desktop` entry and close any open nautilus instances, and the extra dock icon should go away.

you may do a `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop` from a terminal to remove it.

Comment: perhaps be more clear on how you deleted it - some might have a difficulty with that

Comment: @db429 Thanks. I have updated my answer.